# Como ter duas versões do php no mesmo servidor Apache?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

Tenho um servidor Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) rodando um site em php 5.5. Porém eu estou criando um novo site e ele precisa do php 5.6. Tem como ter duas versões do php instalado no meu servidor e usar cada um em pastas diferentes?

Comment: Curiosidade: existe algum problema de usar a 5.6 em ambos? Da 5.5 para a 5.6 não deve ter mudado tanto. Aliás, por que ainda a versão 5 e não a 7, que é a mais recente?

Comment: Basicamente o servidor comporta outros sistemas, como por exemplo um sistema de câmeras e eu não tenho contato com o desenvolvedor. Mudar a versão do php pode fzr com que tudo que já está no servidor pare de funcionar!

Comment: Concordo que caso as versões sejam muito próximas não terá diferença, mas caso sejam estas muito distantes poderá interferir no funcionamento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exemplo no Linux Mint 18

Asumindo que o Apache está instalado, criado o host virtual para os dois projetos e adicionafo os necessarios php PPAs. Vamos supor o projeto site56.local em php5.6 e o projeto site70.local no php7.0.

Instale php5.6-fpm e php7.0fpm com o seguinte comando:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

Crie dois arquivos em /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ e salve

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi

sudo nano /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi
```

Abra o php56 conf arquivo "/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5.6-fpm.conf" adicione as seguintes configurações e salve.

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c> AddHandler php56-fcgi .php Action php56-fcgi /php56-fcgi Alias /php56-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization Action php70-fcgi /php70-fcgi Alias /php70-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization </IfModule> <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin> Require all granted </Directory>
```

Agora habilite a nova configuração do Apache.

```
sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
```

Se você instalou o php5.6 e php5.7, veriique se você desativou os dois e reiniciou o Apache.

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 php7.0

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Crie um arquivo .htacces no projeto que deve estar no php7.0 e adicione o seguinte Handler.

```
AddHandler php70-fcgi .php
```

Agora crie um arquivo phpinfo no projeto e veja se funcionou.

**Nota: Verifique se o htaccess está habilitado em seu apache2.conf ou httpd.conf.**

site56:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

site70:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]